# Firebase setCurrentScreen duplicates log entries screen_view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I need to display statistics on open screens in firebase (as before in analytics.google)

And I need to display not real class names like MainActivity, but for example ScreenSeviceList

I created a test project consisting of 4 Activity and 3 Fragment(in MainActivity4)

```
class App : Application() {
companion object{
    lateinit var mFirebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics
}
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
     mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
}
```

}

all Activity contain approximately the same code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    button2.setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(baseContext,Main2Activity::class.java)) }
    button3.setOnClickListener {  startActivity(Intent(baseContext,Main3Activity::class.java))}
    button4.setOnClickListener {  startActivity(Intent(baseContext,Main4Activity::class.java))}

}
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    App.mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, null, "ScreenActivity#1")
}
```

}

And Activity4 have 3 Fragment like

```
class Fragment1 :Fragment(){

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,container,false)
    view.fragment_title.text="====Fragment#1===="
    view.button_prev.setOnClickListener { activity!!.goToFragment(0) }
    view.button_next.setOnClickListener { activity!!.goToFragment(2) }
    return view
}
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    App.mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(activity!!, null, "ScreenFragment#1")
   }
```

}

In firebase console DebugView, when I switch screen. I see two event screen_view
First even `firebase_screen_class = MainActivity` 
Second even `firebase_screen_class = ScreenActivity#1`
For fragment all work well
How not to register automatic events like `MainActivity`, but to register only your own such as `ScreenActivity#1`? As you can see in the picture below, the entries are duplicated and, as a result, the values ​​are incorrect. For example, instead of showing the line of `ScreenActivity#1 18 28%`, we see two of 14%

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is certainly not elegant, but maybe someone will come in handy.
If someone knows a more beautiful solution, then I will be glad to see it

```
    override fun onResume() {
    App.mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
    super.onResume()
    App.mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
    App.mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "ScreenActivity#1", "ScreenActivity#1")
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason you're not content with simply setting the screen name instead of overriding screen class?

Comment: customer requirement that all names in the console be in Russian
This training project

Comment: It's worth noting that with this workaround `firebase_previous_class` parameter would be incorrect - it would point to the current activity.